# Shadow copy in c# wpf is not copying my c++ dlls (unmanaged code)

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, shadow-copy

I have an application in wpf c# which uses c++ dlls also. When I try to update this application using AppDomain and setting ShadowCopyFiles to true, it creates a cache folder and my application launches from there. However it does not copy my c++ dlls (unmanaged code) and the application access them from the original bin folder. Because of the same I am not able to update my c++ dlls. 
A similar question already exists [Shadow Copying, and mixed C# and C++ DLLs loading from arbitrary folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272030/shadow-copying-and-mixed-c-sharp-and-c-dlls-loading-from-arbitrary-folders) but I didn't find any suitable answer.